# Haskell averaging error

Tags: haskell, average

I just need some help with my following code. I am trying to give the average of the website ratings for the films of a given director.

However i seem to get an error when running the following code. The error is: Invalid type signature: DirectorAverage :: String -> Float
    Should be of form  ::

I can't seem to spot whats wrong with the code as i believe i have programmed the code correctly and i would appreciate it if someone could help solve this error!

Thanks!

```
import Data.List 
import Text.Printf

type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])


testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]),
                ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
                ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
                ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
                ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
                ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
                ("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
                ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
                ("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
                ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
                ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
                ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
                ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
                ("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
                ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
                ("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
                ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
                ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])]         


--Some functions needed later on:
averageFilmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averageFilmRating ratings
     = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd ratings)) / (fromIntegral(length ratings))

--Formats the films for decimal, gives average rating of films instead of all users ratings.
formatFilm :: Film -> String
formatFilm (title, director, year, rating)
     = printf "%s by %s. Year: %d, Average Rating: %.1f" (title) (director) (year) (averageFilmRating rating)    


displayByDirector :: String -> [Film]
displayByDirector name
     =  filter(\(_,director,_,_) -> director == name) testDatabase

DirectorAverage :: String -> Float
DirectorAverage dir
     = averageFilmRating [ (user,rating) | (title, director, year, [(user, rating)]) <- displayByDirector dir]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case is used in Haskell to distinguish the names of types, which start with a capital letter, from the names of values, which start with a lowercase letter. (Note that a function is a value in Haskell.)

Thus `DirectorAverage` is an invalid name for a function. By convention, your function should be named `directorAverage`:

```
directorAverage :: String -> Float
directorAverage dir
     = averageFilmRating [ (user,rating) | (title, director, year, [(user, rating)]) <- displayByDirector dir]
```

Comment: Even so that fixes the error, i dont know why i made a silly mistake like that, my results are coming up as NaN, ive never seen this before and not too sure why. Help?

Comment: @user3411002 Your pattern match of `[(user, rating)]` in `directorAverage` is incorrect, that means it will only work for directors who have movies with 1 rating.  You really want to do something like `[rating | (title, director, year, ratings) <- displayByDirector dir, rating <- ratings]`, or more simply `concat [ratings | (_, _, _, ratings) <- displayByDirecor dir]`.

Comment: Thanks, i havent read too much into concat but will read into that now and apply it here. Thanks for the solution!! Works well now!